# Problem with installing Ubuntu 12.04 lts while having windows 7 already on laptop

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I already have windows 7 on my laptop, and I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on that too.When I am installing Ubuntu its asking for restore full hard drive. How do I install both?

Comment: Completely shutdown windows. Check the harddrive for errors using `chkdsk /f`

Comment: Did you shrink your Windows 7 installation? You must have free space for Ubuntu to be installed on.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new drive with free space and then use tools such as Universal USB installer(available [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) ) to create a bootable disk. Then restart the system and open bios settings and set the boot priority to external disk and save the settings and restart and then install the Ubuntu.